# Calling functions in a for loop to write to a text file using sys.stdout

Tags: python, list, for-loop, sys

So the first two statement in the for-loop execute & are written to the text file but the functions elements (y) have not written to the file. It just appears as "none". Any help appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
def textSummary():
    titles = ["Variable Summary", "Preview of the first & last 5 records in the set, data shape, data types etc.", "Statistical Summary - Mean, median, standard deviations etc.", "Statistical Summary of each Species"]
    funList = [dataInfo(), summaryAll(), summaryBySpecies(), countSpecies()]
    sys.stdout = open ('variableSummary.txt', 'w') 
    for x, y in zip(titles, funList):
        print(x)
        print(astrixBorder())
        y
```

Comment: is the return value of `astrixBorder()` `None`?

Comment: A simple "y" is only evaluated (and maybe shown in a Python shell) but not written to a file or stream.

Comment: No, the astrixBorder is just a line of asterisks (spelt that wrong) to give form to the text file. They printed fine and so did the titles.

Comment: Exactly Michael, it is output in the shell but not written to the text file.

Comment: Then I don't understand the problem.

Comment: What is `y`?  If it's a value you wish to print, then use `print(y)`.  If it's a function that needs to be called then call it `y()`, or call it and print it `print(y())`.  Decide what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my guess at what is happening.

First you have probably defined `astrixBorder` like this (or similar):

```
def astrixBorder():
  print("this")
  print("that")
```

Although you have not written it explicitly, the return value here is `None`, the same as if you had written.

```
def astrixBorder():
  print("this")
  print("that")
  return None
```

This means that the `print` calls in your `for` loop are in effect:

```
print(x)
print(None) # and as a side-effect, print some *'s
```

The `y` in the `for` loop is not printed, since you never do `print(y)`. Printing a value in a non-interactive way (e.g. to a file) is not the same as evaluating an expression in the REPL and seeing *the REPL* print the value for you.

Now it should be clearer why you get the output that you do.

To fix it, simply don't `print` the `astrixBorder()` value, but do `print` the value of `y`. E.g.

```
print(x)
astrixBorder()
print(y)
```

**Also**

As an extra, your way of printing to file by changing `sys.stdout` will likely get you into trouble later on, as well as confuse readers of your code. I think you probably settled on this approach because `astrixBorder` prints to stdout. But the better, clearer way would be to simply change `astrixBorder` to take as argument a output stream, and use the `open` context manager to write to the file (and close automagically). E.g.:

```
def astrixBorder(out):
  print("this", file=out)
  print("that", file=out)

  
def textSummary():
  titles = ["Variable Summary", "Preview of the first & last 5 records in the set, data shape, data types etc.", "Statistical Summary - Mean, median, standard deviations etc.", "Statistical Summary of each Species"]
  funList = [dataInfo(), summaryAll(), summaryBySpecies(), countSpecies()]
  with open('variableSummary.txt', 'w') as out:
    for x, y in zip(titles, funList):
      print(x, file=out)
      astrixBorder(out)
      print(y, file=out)
```

Comment: Excellent! Ok, so I followed what you suggested & the first two statements execute perfectly and write to the text file. The functions all have print statements already contained in them. If I define a parameter for the other functions, then every time those functions are called it will write to the text file?

Comment: Sorry, im getting "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" for the functions. So there must be a NoneType being returned somewhere but there are only print statements inside the functions. I thought that if there was a print statement inside a function then this is considered to be the return? Or does it also return none as well?

Comment: Without seeing the definitions for the other functions, it's hard to tell... but having a print statement inside a function does not affect its return. If you don't have an explicit `return` statement then the return value of the function will be `None`